# How can I access pipeline parameters from data flow?

Tags: parameters, transformation, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a parameter (type int). Inside the pipeline, at one point, I have a data flow. This data flow needs to reference this parameter in order to filter data by it and add it as a new derived column. However, from the data flow, I am unable to access the parameter defined in the pipeline in which the data flow itself resides.

Pipeline:

```
    {
    "name": "TestPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "TestDataFlow",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "TestDataFlow",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "CompanyId": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data flow:

```
    {
    "name": "TestDataFlow",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DBEmployee",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "Employees",
                    "script": "source(output(\n\t\tId as long,\n\t\tName as string,\n\t\tSurname as string,\n\t\tEmail as string,\n\t\tPosition as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'table') ~> Employees"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "AddColumnId",
                    "script": "Employees derive(ColumnId = ERROR_FUNCTION('@pipeline(__SINGLE_QUOTE__TestPipeline__SINGLE_QUOTE__).parameters.CompanyId')) ~> AddColumnId"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My query is simple. How can I access the pipeline's parameter "CompanyId" from the transformations inside the dataflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used a parameter to filter incoming data from the dataset in a data flow but not seen how to reference a parameter in a data flow to do manipulation within the flow (i.e. does not appear in the list available to "filters" blocks for example).  Could you take in the parameter, send it to the source as part of the query and then filter and/or return the value as a column in the result set and do it that way?  Have not tried this.

**Referencing a pipeline  parameter:**

If you have a dataset with a parameter, then the dataflow will be able to supply that parameter in the dataflow settings panel (appears under "source parameters"). That value can be supplied from the pipeline parameter.  *Without the dataset parameter - the "source parameters" option does not appear.*

In the example below, source1 is my dataset reference in the dataflow dataflow1.  It takes a parameter called "test".

My pipeline has a parameter called Test1.  This is passed to the dataflow.

Note the warning in the UI about how to debug.

```
{
"name": "pipeline1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "dataflow1",
            "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataflow": {
                    "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                    "type": "DataFlowReference",
                    "datasetParameters": {
                        "source1": {
                            "test": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.Test1",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "Test1": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't work. But neither I can make it work as per their documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameters-data-flow?source=docs

Answer (score 0):

Your Data flow parameter has to be of STRING type for you to choose the parameter from the pipeline. You can always convert this string to another datatype in your Data Flow if you want to use a date or an integer in your data flow.